# Trouble with videoplayback in ios 8 uiwebview using xamarin

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin

We have an app (monotouch/ios/xamrin.ios what you you like to call it) which uses a uiwebview for videoplayback. We create the following html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: transparent; color: white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0">
        <video width="100%" height="100%" controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
            <source src="http://onsport.dk/7718125/8254704/f6a4e032d96f26dc127ded126a179e93/video_hd/kalormen-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

and load this in our webview like this `LoadHtmlString(content, null);`. It has been working as it should, but now it does not work anymore. By that I mean that the playback button appears but nothing happens when clicked. I am not sure if it is caused by the newest ios(8) update but it seems to be the only difference from earlier. 
I have tested the html with [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all) and html loads fine

Do anyone have a suggestion to what I am missing.

Comment: Did you update your Xamarin recently? Maybe that's the issue. I just tried your code in Xamarin.iOS 8.4 where it works fine. The new version is 8.6

Comment: I have updated to the newest. However I found that if I set width and height to a fixed number of pixels instead of percentages it would work. Very strange